# Python publish picture attachment to pushover

Tags: python, attachment, pushover

I am successfully sending messages to pushover using the below code, however I would like to send picture attachment as introduced in the latest API. How am I able to convert the last code sample to work in python.

**Working Code:**

```
import httplib, urllib
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection("api.pushover.net:443")
conn.request("POST", "/1/messages.json",
  urllib.urlencode({
    "token": "APP_TOKEN",
    "user": "USER_KEY",
    "message": "hello world",
  }), { "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" })
conn.getresponse()
```

**Sample API**

```
curl -s \
 --form-string "token=APP_TOKEN" \
 --form-string "user=USER_KEY" \
 --form-string "message=here is an image attachment" \
 -F "attachment=@/path/to/your/image.jpg" \
 https://api.pushover.net/1/messages.json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried urllib, but been successful with requests. I don't really know if you want to use that module. But here is the code anyways.

```
import requests

r = requests.post("https://api.pushover.net/1/messages.json", data={"token":"APP_TOKEN","user":"USER_KEY","message":"Got Image?"}, files={"attachment":open("PATH_TO_IMAGE","rb")})
```

To break it down. You pass the requested parameters to be formencoded in the dict **data**. Then you pass the file in the dict **files**. The important thing is that the file is opened rb (read binary).

Comment: Similar to this, if you have an image URL, you can have `requests` download and attach it. Replace `files={"attachment":open("PATH_TO_IMAGE","rb")` with `files={"attachment": requests.get("https://example.com/image.jpg").content}`